# issue in navigating to child view of same level ui-router

Tags: angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I am facing a strange issue with ui-router nested state.
I am using ionic tabs project.
I have the following states:

```
->home

   ->myplace
```

inside myplace I have a button-bar and a ion-nav-view

I am changing the ion-view-content based on button bar.

So myplace is an abstract state for me. 
    ->myplace
      -->enrolments
      -->orders
       -->payments

enrolments, order and payments are my child state of myplace.

**problem**:
In home state view I have a button, on click of it I am redirecting to enrollments state without any issue. And I am able to navigate to orders and payments also there.

But if I try to go to orders state, URL is changing but the template is not loading. Strange.

Enrollments and orders are same level child states. Able to go to enrollments. Template is loading as expected but for orders URL is changing but view is not rendering.

aAny help would be highly appreciated!!

I have tried adding debugging information for statechangeStart, success.
StateChangeStart, StateChangeSuccess both are getting called.
/enrollments:
    $stateChangeStart to undefined- fired when the transition begins. toState,toParams : 
 Object {url: "/enrollments", parent: "footer.home", views: Object, name: "footer.myapp.enrollments", data: Object} Object {}
app.js:55 $stateChangeSuccess to footer.myplace.enrollments- fired once the state transition is complete.
/orders:
    $stateChangeStart to undefined- fired when the transition begins.       toState,toParams : 
     Object {url: "/orders", parent: "footer.home", views: Object, name:     "footer.myapp.orders", data: Object} Object {}
app.js:55 $stateChangeSuccess to footer.myplace.orders- fired once the state transition is complete.

Comment: can you post a well structured code? you can see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: found out the issue. Its all because of tabs **href** property. In <ion-tabs> i gave href property which refers to a states URL.
    <ion-tab href="#/myapp/v1">
         <ion-nav-view name="myparentview"/>    
</ion-tab>

since my view is tied up with that url when i am trying to load view from another url its not loading. **resolved when i changed the href to another state and load that url**.